# Unable to combine 2 Superpower TextParser with Or with Span

Tags: c#, parsing, prefix, superpower

I have 2 Superpower TextParser - each targets to parse a certain input - differentiated by prefix and parameters. I am trying to create a combined parser that gives out the result when either of the TextParser can parse the input. The output is a list with certain strings describing the input.

e.g. Some input and output pair as follows

```
"interrupt(20)" -> List { "interrupt", "20" }
"insert(20,12)" -> List {"insert", "20", "12" }
"delete(18)" -> Error
```

For the sample input and output pairs, I wrote the following in C# with superpower reference added.

```
// Works fine for "insert(12,24)"
string failingTest = "interrupt(12)";

TextParser<List<string>> identifier001 =
    from prefix in Span.EqualTo("insert")
    from open in Character.EqualTo('(')
    from num0 in Character.Numeric.Many()
    from comma1 in Character.EqualTo(',')
    from num1 in Character.Numeric.Many()
    from close in Character.EqualTo(')')
    select new List<string> { prefix.ToStringValue(), string.Join("", num0), string.Join("", num1) };

TextParser<List<string>> identifier002 =
    from prefix in Span.EqualTo("interrupt")
    from open in Character.EqualTo('(')
    from num0 in Character.Numeric.Many()
    from close in Character.EqualTo(')')
    select new List<string> { prefix.ToStringValue(), string.Join("", num0) };

TextParser<List<string>> combined =
    from span in identifier001.Or(identifier002)
    select span;

var res = combined.Parse(failingTest);
foreach (var item in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

My `combined` identifier cannot parse the input `interrupt(12)` and gives the following error

> Syntax error (line 1, column 3): unexpected `t`, expected `s`.

Is there any proper way of doing the "Or" combination of the identifiers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `Try()` after your first parser, then chain it with the `Or()` function, like this:

```
TextParser<List<string>> combined =
    from span in identifier001.Try().Or(identifier002)
    select span;
```

What happens is that your first parser `identifier001` has already consumed the `"in"` portion of the string, which leaves `identifier002` to try and parse the string `"terrupt(20)"` which fails.  The call to `Try()` tells the parser to backtrack to the point of origin of the previous parser, which is what you want.

The documentation on `Try()` is this:

> Construct a parser that tries one parser, and backtracks if unsuccessful so that no input appears to have been consumed by subsequent checks against the result.

Comment: I wonder why this is not the default. Surely consuming input on failure is not a common requirement?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I agree, especially when chaining an `Or()` call on a parser you'd expect it to backtrack automatically. I personally struggled with this for a while too until I combed thru the documentation to find the `Try()` function.  I haven't looked at the source code for Superpower, but there may be a reason for it being this way.

Comment: I looked through the code and opened [this issue](https://github.com/datalust/superpower/issues/118). The library development is very slow lately, though, so I'm not sure if it gets enough traction.